# How to copy multiple files and keep the folder structure with Gulp

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another folder using Gulp:

```
gulp.task('move-css',function(){
  return gulp.src([
    './source/css/one.css',
    './source/other/css/two.css'

    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css/'));
});
```

The above code is copying `one.css` & `two.css` to the `public/assets/css` folder.

And if I use `gulp.src('./source/css/*.css')` it will copy all CSS files to the `public/assets/css` folder which is not what I want.

How do I select multiple files and keep the folder structure?

Comment: @lal css files can be  at different  folders so regular expression is not useful in this case IMHO

Comment: is the issue is like files in multiple folders are copied to the one folder  `public/assets/css` ?

Comment: yupp, exactly , i want to do that

Answer (score 160, accepted):

To achieve this please specify `base`.

> [¶ base](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs#srcglobs-opt%60) - Specify the folder relative to the cwd. Default is where the glob begins. This is used to determine the file names when saving in `.dest()`

---

In your case it would be:

```
gulp.task('move-css',function(){
  return gulp.src([
      './source/css/one.css',
      './source/other/css/two.css'
  ],  {base: './source/'}) 
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/'));
});
```

Folder structure:

```
.
├── gulpfile.js
├── source
│   ├── css
│   └── other
│       └── css
└── public
    └── assets
```

Comment: If your files have completely different directory structures (e.g. `['./lib/one.js', './models/two.js']`) you can add `{base: '.'}` to make it keep their entire structure.

Comment: How to parse every files, folders and subfolders in src ?

Comment: please check src with double ** `gulp.src('**/*.*')`

Answer (score 1):

I use gulp-flatten and use this configuration:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpFlatten = require('gulp-flatten');

var routeSources = {
  dist:  './public/',
  app: './app/',
  html_views: {
    path: 'app/views/**/*.*',
    dist: 'public/views/'
  }
};

gulp.task('copy-html-views', task_Copy_html_views);
function task_Copy_html_views() {
  return gulp.src([routeSources.html_views.path])
      .pipe(gulpFlatten({ includeParents: 1 }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(routeSources.html_views.dist));
}
```

And there you can see the documentation about gulp-flatten: [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten)

Answer (score -3):

```
   gulp.task('move-css',function(){
      return gulp
                  .src([ 'source/**'], { base: './' })
                  .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css/'));
    });
```

Your own code didn't include the entire dir tree of source `'source/**'` and the base `{base:'./'}` when calling to `gulp.src` which caused the function to fail.
The other parts where fine.

```
gulp.task('move-css',function(){
  return gulp.src([
    './source/css/one.css',
    './source/other/css/two.css'

    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./public/assets/css/'));
});
```

Comment: SO frowns on code only Answers. For long term value, helping future visitors learn and apply this knowledge to their own issues, and to increase chances of upvotes, consider adding explanations, highlighting pets of you answer that addresses OP's issue, to your answers.